# How to focus a tab in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

When load to tab page, i want to focus second tab.it is a wpf application.I use MUI template for that.
here is my code

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <!-- TODO: set @SelectedSource -->
    <mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab" AllowDrop="True" Name="tabcontroller" >
        <mui:ModernTab.Links  >
            <!-- TODO: set @Source -->
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Add User"   Source="/Content/Admin/AddUserPage.xaml"/>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Manage User" x:Name="mngser"  Source="/Content/Admin/ManageUserPage.xaml"/>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Add Suplier" Source="/Content/Admin/AddSuplierPage.xaml"/>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Manage Suplier" Source="/Content/Admin/ManageSuplierPage.xaml"/>
        </mui:ModernTab.Links>
    </mui:ModernTab>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `SelectedSource` property of `ModernTab` to the same `Source` as the second tab :

```
........
<mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab" AllowDrop="True" Name="tabcontroller" 
            SelectedSource="/Content/Admin/ManageUserPage.xaml">
........
</mui:ModernTab>
........
```